# Convert uncommon String date/time data to DateTime data type

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, string-to-datetime

I'm trying to implement a PowerShell script to compare DateTime from certificate file(Jave Keystore).

However, the DateTime format that I extract from keystore file is quite complex as example below.

**Mon Mar 13 06:40:26 CDT 2023**

**Sat Sep 18 20:41:47 CDT 2027**

It includes time and timezone in the String but **I actually need only date like 13-Mar-2023**.

Could anyone help suggest how I return this String to be DateTime for comparison?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[datetime]::ParseExact()` method for this:

```
$dateString = 'Mon Mar 13 06:40:26 CDT 2023'

$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss CDT yyyy', [cultureinfo]'en-US')
$date.ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

Result:

> 13-Mar-2023

<sup>CDT means Central Time Zone (UTC - 6), switched to DayLight Saving Time -->  Central Daylight Time (CDT) which is five hours behind UTC</sup>

Comment: Hello Theo, it's very clear and helpful for me. I really appreciate for your help :)